# How to handle space and tabs (and line breaks) in html source

Tags: html, css

When writing clean and well-readable code in html, how to handle linebreaks and spaces

for example if i use break for the next line there is an extra space in between

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {margin:0px; border:1px solid #666; padding:10px; text-decoration:none;}
</style>
<div>
    <a href="#">Test 1</a><a href="#">Test 2</a> <!-- SAME LINE -->
    <a href="#">Test 3</a> <!-- NEW LINE -->
    <a href="#">Test 4</a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YStX/2/)

so what should i do,

is there an standard way to handle this or i just should write all the html code in 1 line if i don't want the space and breaks between tags to act like this

### EDIT:

Thanks guys but i already know extra spaces are shrinked into one and how (enter) acts, the problem is i don't want enter to act like that (put an space between my tags because then i have to hande that space in my style)
, so i don't have to write my code in the same line (i want to write it clean and readable)

### EDIT 2:

I think i have to clear the question a bit more

I need this code:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
    <a href="#">Test 3</a>
</div>
```

to be shown (seen by user) and act like this code: (no extra space in between because of the line breaks or spaces)

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Test 1</a><a href="#">Test 2</a><a href="#">Test 3</a>
</div>
```

this extra space makes me a lot of trouble,

is there a solution for this? maybe styling the body to don't count space and enters "**between tags** (not between the text inside tags of course)" as space in the result?

> ### THE SOLUTION

By reading chiefGui's answer on the last part he mentioned float,
so just by adding float: left; to my code above my problem solved

Online: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YStX/7/)

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {float:left; margin:0px; border:1px solid #666; padding:10px; text-decoration:none;}
</style>
<div>
    <a href="#">Test 1</a><a href="#">Test 2</a> <!-- SAME LINE -->
    <a href="#">Test 3</a> <!-- NEW LINE -->
    <a href="#">Test 4</a>
</div>
```

> ### UPDATE (ANOTHER SOLUTION):

i tried another methods and i think ***display:table-cell;*** is an answer too and maybe its even better because we don't need to clear after that

the only downside is it will not work on IE 7 and earlier versions, although i think it is manageable with a simple ***lt IE 8*** hack

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YStX/8/)

Comment: @Oriol You know some one is spending too much time here when they are Gravedigging a 2 years old question to mark it as duplicate... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I wanted to give some use to my new dupehammer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most semantic way to break a line with pure HTML is using `<br/>` tag.

See:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {margin:0px; border:1px solid #666; padding:10px; text-decoration:none;}
</style>
<div>
    <a href="#">Test 1</a><a href="#">Test 2</a><br />
    <a href="#">Test 3</a><br />
    <a href="#">Test 4</a>
</div>
```

There is a lot of prejudice about `<br/>`, but in this case you can use without problems.

### Updated

When you have a list of items like you showed to us, firstly, the right thing to do is put all the links in a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Secondly, to align them on the same line, use the `display: inline;` property. See:

```
ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Or, if you wish, depending of your code, you can float the elements. Look:

```
ul li {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: He does'nt want linebreaks between the hyperlinks.

Comment: thanks, i know about lists, that was a simple example code, but your float:left; was the solution, i guess i should use clearafter for each ul too

Comment: Yes, a clear fix it is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple whitespaces (space, enter, tab, etc.) are shrinked to a single space by browser. The only exceptions are:

Tag "pre":

```
<pre>
    Your    text   with    original   spacing
</pre>
```

And `&...` things like:

```
A&nbsp;&nbsp;B(this will have two spaces between A & B)
```

So in your case: `link1(no space)link2(enter)link3(enter)link4` is essentially `link1link2 link3 link4`

And if you want to force newline - use `<br>` tag.

Comment: `<textarea>` is an exception too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem in writing the code on more than one line. Just take care if you set a block-element to something like:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

because then the whitespaces between the elements are shown in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple whitespace characters are squashed together to one (if not specified otherwise).

So your only option is to write all links on a single line.

Comment: i was thinking that too, but look at my updates

Answer (score 0):

use ul li is good way to create tabs like

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
a {
    margin: 0px; 
    border: 1px solid #666; 
    padding: 10px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #efefef;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
ul li{
 display:inline;
}
```

for manage space margin is better way

Answer (score 0):

You can also use html comments:

```
<div><!--
    --><a href="#">Test 1</a><!--
    --><a href="#">Test 2</a><!--
    --><a href="#">Test 3</a><!--
--></div>
```

It's readable for humans and all whitespaces are commented out for html parsers.